# In trapezium ABCD, if BC = 3cm then AD = ?Given...

Tags: geometry

In trapezium $ABCD$, $AB || CD$. Diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ meet at $O$. Area$(\triangle ABO)$ : area$(\triangle CDO) = 1:6$. If $BC = 3$cm, find $AD$.

I know that $\triangle ABO$ and $\triangle CDO$ are similar and the ratio of their corresponding sides is $1:\sqrt6$. Also,
area$(\triangle BCO) =$ area$(\triangle ADO)$.

Comment: What else is given? I have got $$d^2=\frac{17}{3}BO^2+3-AO^2$$

Comment: Nothing else is given...sorry.But, how did you get the equation?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single answer.

For example: assume $AB = 1$, so that $CD=\sqrt6$.

Then, if we assume $ABCD$ is symmetrical this gives $AD=3$, but if instead we assume, say, that $\angle BCD$ is a right angle, then $AD$ = $\sqrt{3^2+(\sqrt{6}-1)^2}\simeq3.332.$

[image]

Comment: Nice, but how can that be an answer?

Comment: These are only special cases.

Comment: By providing two cases where the length of $AD$ differs I have shown that there is insufficent information to determine $AD$ uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the equations
$$6AO\times BO=CO\times D=$$
$$AO\times DO=CO\times BO$$
$$d^2=AO^2+DO^2-2AO\times DO\times \cos(\pi-\delta)$$
$$9=BO^2+CO^2-2BO\times CO\times \cos(\pi-\delta)$$

Comment: Okay thanks. I think that the question was incomplete to start with :-(